# An elegant way to extract 'Date' attribute from a File

Tags: java, scala, file, attributes, filesystems

So I have multiple files (on Windows 10 operating system and NTFS file system) with 'Date' attributes as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOCvC.png)

'Date' attributes are available in Windows File Explorer in the 'Details' view after enabling them.

I'm looking for the easiest way to extract this attribute in Java (or Scala). I've read about solutions that can extract modification/creation time but neither of them mentioned a 'Date' attribute alone.

Comment: Post text rather than images, wherever practical.

Comment: Your Question lacks details. What operating system? What file system? What app?

Comment: @BasilBourque I edited the question and added information. I think that image gives useful information about where one can find the 'Date' attribute.

Comment: I don’t know Windows, and I certainly know no `Date` attribute of an NTFS file. Is it the last access date and time? Just a wild guess. If my guess is correct, you may look into [`BasicFileAttributes.lastAccessTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastAccessTime()).

Comment: Whatever that Date column is, it doesn’t appear to be the modification time, the last access time, or the creation time.  Which leads me to wonder if it’s specific to Microsoft Office documents.  For all other files, it appears to be the same as the modification time.

Comment: @VGR You are right, I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this 'Date' attribute has the same value as 'Last Saved Date' which is attribute specific to Microsoft Office or only (?) Excel files...
The method to extract this data from a file in Scala (if you use org.apache.poi.hssf library) can look something like this

```
def getLastSaveDateTime(file: File): Date = {
  val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
  try {
    val workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)
    workbook.getSummaryInformation.getLastSaveDateTime
  } finally fileInputStream.close()
}
```